# Field required attribute acidentially invoked but clicking a button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, textbox, requiredfieldvalidator, dropdownlistfor

I have these fields, and I implemented required attribute on them.

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "ChannelsGrid", FormMethod.Post, new {name = "channelForm", @class = "channelForm", @enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Id)
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-6">

                @Html.Label("Part/Location", new {@class = "control-label"})
                @Html.TextBox("PartLocation", null, new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required" })

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">

                @Html.Label("Index", new {@class = "control-label"})
                @Html.TextBox("Index", null, new {@class = "form-control"})

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">

                @Html.Label("Measurement", new {@class = "control-label"})
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Measurement, (SelectList)ViewBag.Measurements, "-- Select Measurement --", new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required" })


            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">

                @Html.Label("Location", new {@class = "control-label"})
                @Html.DropDownList("Directions", ViewBag.DirectionTypes as List<SelectListItem>, "-- Select Direction --", new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required" })


            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">

                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ChannelGroupId, new {@class = "control-label"})
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ChannelGroupId, Model.ChannelGroups, "Select Channel Group", new {@class = "form-control"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ChannelGroupId)

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <label class="control-label"></label>
                <a href="#" id="addChannelGroup" class="form-control" style="border: none">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus-circle">Add Group</i>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <label class="control-label"></label>
                <a href="#" id="addMeasurement" class="form-control" style="border: none">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus-circle">Add Measurement</i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.Label("Channel name: ", new {id = "channelName", @class = "control-label"})
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.TextBox("HiddenTextBox", null, new {@class = "hidden"})
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Name, new {@class = "hidden"})
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row" id="pnlAddChannelGroupName" style="display: none">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label">Channel Group Name :</label>
            <input type="text" id="ChannelGroupName" name="ChannelGroupName" class="form-control"/>
            <input type="button" value="Cancel" id="channelGroupButton" />
            @*<button id="channelGroupButton">Cancel</button>*@
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row" id="pnlMeasurement" style="display: none">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @Html.Label("Measurement :", new {@class = "control-label"})
            @Html.TextBox("MeasurementName", null, new {@class = "form-control"})
            <input type="button" value="Cancel" id="measurementButton" />
            @*<button id="measurementButton">Cancel</button>*@
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I also have two buttons which are used to toggle other textboxes in this form. Here is the code.

```
    <div class="row" id="pnlAddChannelGroupName" style="display: none">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label">Channel Group Name :</label>
            <input type="text" id="ChannelGroupName" name="ChannelGroupName" class="form-control"/>
            <button id="channelGroupButton">Cancel</button>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row" id="pnlMeasurement" style="display: none">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @Html.Label("Measurement :", new {@class = "control-label"})
            @Html.TextBox("MeasurementName", null, new {@class = "form-control"})
            <button id="measurementButton">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The problem is whenever I click these two Cancel buttons in that field, the three fields seems to be invoked and there is brown border around the textbox dropdownlist. I guess these field have been submitted. But I thought I use button element instead of type button of an input so I can eliminate the submitting action of the button, right? Any clues? And how can I click these Cancel buttons withouts invoking validation in these other field?

**Edited:** I changed all the buttons to input type="button"  and the validation of these other field dissapeared. Can someone explain?

This is my viewmodel:

```
namespace CrashTestScheduler.Entity.ViewModel
{
    public class ChannelViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        //[Display(Name = "Name")]
        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please specify the channel name.")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string ChannelGroupName { get; set; }

        public string MeasurementName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a channel group.")]
        public int ChannelGroupId { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ChannelGroups { get; set; }

        //[Required]
        public string Measurement { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Depending on the browser, the default action for `<button>` may be to submit. You should always add the type - `<button type="button" ....>`

Comment: I use Chrome. I read somewhere that if i use button not type="button" I should not worry about posting something to server or submitting things. So is this not the case in Chrome? And can you explain why the validations got invoked? This is client side validation so I thought I can only invoke them when I hit save button to submit the field to somewhere, right?

Comment: The default in Chrome is to submit (at least my version). You should always explicitly set the `type` attribute. Its hard to understand why you would add `@required = "required"`. Do it properly and add validation attributes to your properties and use `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` so  you get client side and server side validation. And there is so much other bad code here - such as incorrect labels which are not even associated with your controls.

Comment: @Stephen: My boss wants me to hard code in this case which I have to do things like this in controller:    var direction = neList<SelectListItem>();
            direction.Add(new SelectListItem {Text = "X", Value = "0"});
            direction.Add(new SelectListItem {Text = "Y", Value = "1"});
            direction.Add(new SelectListItem {Text = "Z", Value = "2"});
            ViewBag.DirectionTypes = direction; Is there anyway to create a model from this code and use your suggested validation?

Comment: Sure, just create a view model with the properties you want to display/edit in the view, but I don't understand what the 2 buttons you have shown are supposed to be doing, and what is the javascript associated with them?

Comment: Since I already have a viewmodel for the whole page, if now I add another property to this viewmodel which is a list of selectlistitems and populate this property in controller. So I can use @Html.ValidationMessageFor(), am I right? I have these Cancel buttons because I let users either chose data from a dropdownlist or they can click two other buttons which enable two textboxes and they can manually enter values. If somehow they change their mind, they can click these Cancel buttons to switch back to the dropdownlist.

Comment: Can you include the view model you currently have.

Comment: @StephenMuecke you can see above

Comment: Need to finish off some other work. I will suggest some improvements to make this a bit more robust a bit later. In the meantime you should look at plugins such as jquery autocomplete which allow you to select from a list or type in a value.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your form is submitting when clicking buttons is that the default action for a `<button>` element is `type="submit"` (refer [documentation](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/button)). You need to explicitly set the `type` attribute

```
<button type="button" ....>
```

However you have numerous issues with your approach.

1. By removing the `[Required]` attributes and using the `required =
   "required"` html attribute, you now need to include manual
   validation on the controller (never trust the user!)
2. Your mixing up Razor and manual html in the view, potentially
   creating problems for model binding. Some of your label elements
   wont work. (e.g. the first one is associated with a control named
   "Part/Location" but there is no control named "Part/Location").
3. The user interface where your force users to click buttons to swap
   between textboxes and dropdown lists is confusing and a sure way to
   lose customers. Instead you should use an autocomplete control such
   as [jQuery Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) which allows selection from a list or
   direct text entry.

Your view model should contain validation attributes for its properties and can be simplified to

```
public class ChannelViewModel
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  [Display(Name = "Part/Location")]
  [Required]
  public string PartLocation { get; set; }
  public string Index { get; set; }
  [Required]
  public string Measurement { get; set; }
  [Required]
  [Display(Name = "Location")]
  public int Direction { get; set; }
  .... // other properties
  public SelectList DirectionList { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Id)

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.PartLocation, new {@class = "control-label"})
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PartLocation, new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PartLocation)

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Index, new {@class = "control-label"})
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Index, new {@class = "form-control"})

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Measurement, new {@class = "control-label"})
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Measurement, new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Measurement)

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Direction, new {@class = "control-label"})
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Direction, Model.DirectionList, "-- Select Direction --", new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Direction)

.... // more controls
```

The attach the autocomplete to `$(#Measurement).autocomplete({...`

This will give you client and server side validation out of the box, and a better user interface.